# Running multiple timers?

Tags: lua, nodemcu

I've got nodemcu and trying to achieve the following.
- Every 5 mins send data to a remote website.
- Every 1 second check sensors

So have 2 functions:

```
   function checkSensors()
        print("checking sensors")
        -- do some stuff here
   end

   function sendData()
        print("Sending Data")
        -- do some stuff here
   end

   tmr.alarm(0, 1000, 1, function() checkSensors() end )
   tmr.alarm(0, 300000, 1, function() sendData() end )
```

If I comment out the first tmr then every 5 mins secs the function sendData is called. Likewise commenting out the first tmr the function sendData is called every sec.

However with both in on sendData is called.

How can I use both timers, or is there another way I'm supposed to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter to `tmr.alarm` is the ID of the timer. Because you use `0` for both calls, this simply reconfigures one timer twice. If you want multiple timers, you need to pass different IDs for each one.

There are 7 static timers (`0`-`6`), though these are going away. You can create dynamic timers with [`tmr.create`](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/modules/tmr/#tmrcreate). The returned ID can be passed to `tmr.alarm`.

Comment: Ahh yes...missed that! Thanks. Been struggling for ages :)